# AWS Athena map query

Tags: amazon-athena

The table has a column like this,

```
data  MAP<string, string>
```

and rows like,

```
id | data
1  | {"foo": 123}
2  | {"bar": 456}
```

Then, how can i search data["bar"] = 456?
I tried but it shows me the error "Column 'bar' cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found i was wrong.
" shouldn't be used in query. ' should be used!
so,

```
WHERE data['foo'] = 123
```

will be worked.

Comment: Right answer! Great.

Comment: 'double quotes should not be used in queries' - Thnx for that! helped me solve my string comparison issue

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, had to resolve by adding the same attribute to all the map data.

You need to have `foo` and `bar` in every map data if you want to query on that.

If the property is not there, it does not know how to resolve to that column.

If you access the whole object as it is, then you don't need to have it.

Hope it help.